# Div in list element jumping when animating hide/show

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div inside of a list element.  I am hiding/showing the div everytime they click on the parent list element.  The functionality is working, however the animation is jumping at the end of the animation.  I think it has to do with the parent list element changing height everytime the div inside hides/shows.  I can't seem to figure out how to deal with it.  I think it's a CSS issue?

[**LINK TO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypxLx/)

**HTML:**

```
<li id='band'>
  <h3>BAND</h3>
    <div class='content'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#centerpage ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#centerpage ul li p {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    var $el = $('#links ul li');

    $el.each(function() {
        var $content = $(this).children().filter('.content');
        var height = $content.height();
        $content.hide().css({ height: 0});
        var listheight = $(this).height();
        console.log(listheight);

        $(this).click(function() {

            var $content = $(this).children().filter('.content');
            if ( $content.is(':visible') ) {
                $content.animate( {
                    height: 0
                }, 1000, function() {   
                    $content.hide();

                });
            }

            else {
                $content.show().animate({ height: height }, { duration: 1000} );
            }

        })  

    })

})
```

Comment: When you say "jumping", what exactly you mean? I've created a fiddle and I can't see anything "jumping"

Comment: Which browser are you using? It looks fine to me in FF.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JURUX/
I'm not seeing the issue here, but I've run into it before. Sometimes it's caused by padding/margin/height discrepancies between the item being hidden and the height of the parent `<li>`

Comment: It's working fine in the jsfiddle for me too, but not on my project.  When I set the list element height explicitly to something greater than what the div inside would expand into, there was no jumping.

Comment: Aha, think I found it.  My <h3> tag didn't have any CSS styling, I set the margin to 0 and it's not jumping anymore.

Comment: Not sure if it is just me, but none of these were working in IE8 for me.